# I cannot get my WIX installer to create shortcuts in the Windows start menu

Tags: windows-installer, wix3

This is an "anonymized" version of my .wxs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="MyProgram" Level="1">
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
    </Feature>

    <Feature Id="MyProgramShortcuts">
        <ComponentRef Id="ProggieShortcut"></ComponentRef>
    </Feature>
</Product>
<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFiles64Folder">
            <Directory Id="MyCompanyFolder" Name ="My Company">
                <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="My Program" />
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
        <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
            <Directory Id="MyProgramFolder" Name="Company">
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Directory>

    <DirectoryRef Id="MyProgramFolder">
        <Component Id="ProggieShortcut" Guid="PUT-GUID-HERE">
            <Shortcut Id="ProggieStartMenuShortcut"
                      Name="Company"
                      Description="Company"
                      Target="[MyProggie.exe]"></Shortcut>
            <RemoveFolder Id="CleanUpProggieShortCut" Directory="MyProgramFolder" On="uninstall"/>
            <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\My Company\My Program" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>
        </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
</Fragment>

<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
        <Component Id="Proggie" Guid="PUT-GUID-HERE">
            <File Id="MyProggie.exe" Name="MyProggie.exe" Source="$(var.MyProggie_TargetDir)MyProggie.exe" />
        </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```

My problem is that no shortcut appears anywhere.

I tried to follow the instructions in https://wixtoolset.org/docs/v3/howtos/files_and_registry/create_start_menu_shortcut/ but either I am doing something wrong without realising it or there is something missing from the instructions perhaps?

One thing I did notice was that in the instructions it tells me to set the Target as follows

```
 Target="[#MyProggie.exe]"
```

But if I do that it returns an ICE69 error:

ICE69: Mismatched component reference. Entry 'ProggieStartMenuShortcut' of the Shortcut table belongs to component 'ProggieShortcut'. However, the formatted string in column 'Target' references file 'MyProggie.exe' which belongs to component 'Proggie'. Components belong to different features

Removing the hash # was the only thing that allowed me to even build this .msi

How do I get this to work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wix - ICE60 and ICE69 warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21320334/wix-ice60-and-ice69-warnings)

Comment: Thanks Bob... my weekend has started but I will investigate on Monday